# Оптимизация заполнения таблицы в MS Word

Tags: c#, html, com, ms-word, office-interop

У меня стоит задачка в заполнении таблицы в MS Word.
Пытаюсь сделать двумя способами:
В первом способе требуется ускорить процесс заполнения таблицы, занимает очень много времени на 1500 записей 15-20 минут.

Во втором способе проблема с получением вставленной таблицы.
Я ее пытаюсь получить из текущего Word.Range (Word.Range.Tables[1]), в который вставляю таблицу, но мне почему-то не возвращает мою таблицу. Пока только на одном компьютере, не знаю как исправить эту ситуацию. Вставка таблицы через HTML файл не лучший вариант, потому что потом нужно доставлять многострочный текст и картинки.

1) Заполняю таблицу очень просто.

```
Word.Table.AddRow();  
Word.Row[indexRow].Cell[indexColumn].Range.Text = "Требуемый текст"
```

2) Заполнение таблицы заключается в том, что я сначала создаю HTML файл с таблицей, потом вставляю этот файл в MS Word.

```
Word.Range.InsertFile("path.html")
```

Место куда вставляю определяю через закладку в шаблоне.

```
Word.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks["Table"].Range
```

Требуется совместимость с MS Word 2003 - 2013.
Сторонние библиотеки использовать не могу, только стандартную Interop.Microsoft.Word.

Comment: тут возможно полезная инфа - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221020/adding-text-to-a-ms-word-table-in-vb-net-too-slow#25228950

Comment: Такой подход уже пробовал, при многострочном тексте не сработало у меня. Может я что то не так делал))

При многострочном тексте Word думал, что это новая строка, и не понятно как вставлять картинки при таком подходе

Answer (score 1):

Самое просто- это отказаться от тормознутого interop в пользу OpenXml.

В отличии от *.doc, который является бинарным форматом, *.`docx`- представляет собой контейнер с *.`xml` файлами(`OpenXml` формат), что позволяет работать с файлом используя сторонние библиотеки, например `EPPlus`.

После того, как вы сделали все необходимые операции вы можете через `interop` сохранить файл в более низкой версии(.`doc`) и это должно быть быстрее.

Это можно реализовать в качестве WCF-сервиса на котором будет стоять свежий офис.

Сервис будет манпипулировать данными в формате .docx, а возвращать .doc.

На мой взгляд, это самое быстрое решение.

Comment: Тут уже я ничего сделать не смогу,  минимальная конфигурация, на которой должно мое приложение запускаться - Это Windows XP и MS Word 2003

Comment: @dosymep, можно поставить бесплатный office engine 2007 или как он там называется... Это офис без интерфейса, но с фозможностью использовать его возможности. Т.е конвертировать форматы вы сумеете.

Comment: Опять же не могу сделать такое))

Comment: @dosymep, а если сделать веб-сервис, который будет иметь нормальный офис и на своей стороне выполнять эти манипуляции над форматом docx, а клиенту возвращать doc?

Comment: На мой взгляд самое простое решение, нежели возиться с тормознутым interop...

Comment: Откуда я возьму веб сервис? Я полностью с тобой согласен, но у меня такие ограничения. Ничего не могу использовать кроме установленного Word и .NET 3.5.

Comment: @dosymep, можно написать с помощью WCF, который доступен в framework 3.0+

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, вообще первый раз использовал ActiveX. Да еще и для Microsoft Word'а. Просто хотелось посмотреть всеж быстродействие. В принципе, получилось. Записываем следующий код в файл `test.js` и выполняем:

```
var app = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
    app.Visible = true;
var doc = app.Documents.Add();
var range = doc.Paragraphs(doc.Paragraphs.Count).Range;
    range.Text = "1,data12,data13\n"+
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+    // тут для теста
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+    // можно добавить
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+    // еще 3000
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+    // подобных строк
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+
                 "1,data32,data33\n"+
                 "1,data22,data23\n"+
                 "1,data32,data33\n";
var table = range.ConvertToTable(",",1,3);
    table.Borders.Enable = 1;
    table.Columns(1).SetWidth(32,0);
```

Должен сформироваться документ с таблицей.

Извините, что на JavaScript'е - C# не знаю, впрочем, как и JavaScript тоже :). Но на С# и пробовать не на чем. Тем не менее, мой скрипт делал таблицу на 3000 строк в Microsoft Word около секунды-полторы. Я думаю, переделать на C# труда особого не составит.

**Вариант с загрузкой HTML (JavaScript)**

Получился вот такой вариант:

```
var app = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
    app.Visible = true;
var doc = app.Documents.Add();
var parag = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
    parag.Range.Font.Bold = true;
    parag.Range.Font.Color = 0xCF7214;
    parag.Range.Font.Size = 18;
    parag.Range.Text = "Это такой заголовок таблицы\n";
    parag = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
    range = doc.Paragraphs(doc.Paragraphs.Count).Range;
    range.InsertFile("C:\\temp\\table.html");
    parag = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
    parag.Range.Text = "Всего таблиц в документе: " + doc.Tables.Count;
var table = doc.Tables(1);
    table.Columns(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = "Заголовок-1";
    table.Columns(2).Cells(1).Range.Text = "Заголовок-2";
    table.Columns(3).Cells(1).Range.Text = "Заголовок-3";
    table.Columns(1).Cells(1).Range.Font.Bold = true;
    table.Columns(2).Cells(1).Range.Font.Bold = true;
    table.Columns(3).Cells(1).Range.Font.Bold = true;
    table.Columns(1).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1;
    table.Columns(2).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1;
    table.Columns(3).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1;
    table.Borders.Enable = true;
```

Сам HTML- файл:

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td valign="center">A</td><td valign="center">B</td><td valign="center">C</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="file:///C:/Temp/!pic.png"></td><td>1</td><td>11</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="file:///C:/Temp/!pic.png"></td><td>2</td><td>22</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Результат:

[image]

Comment: Вопрос, Как в этом способе будет многостночный текст в ячейке отрабатывать, и как вставлять картинки?

Comment: Боюсь, данным способом - никак. `*.doc` формат не поддерживает внедренные картинки, а `*.csv` формат с переводом строк - поддерживается только функцией импорта, но никак не вставкой простого текста с преобразованием в таблицу.

Comment: Добавил вариант загрузки таблицы из внешнего `HTML` - файла

Comment: я таким же способом вставляю сейчас, но проблема Range, в который я вставляю не возвращает на одном компьютере таблицу, и если изображение больше по размеру ячейки, тогда форматирование таблицы едет.

Comment: Я думаю, нужно сперва добиться нормального отображения `HTML` в браузере. А потом, после вставки в `Word`  - играться с атрибутами ячеек. Но, увы, дальше уж вы сами. В том коде, который я привел - доступ к объекту `таблица`, как видно из кода - есть. Таким образом, ваш вопрос "но мне почему-то не возвращает мою таблицу" частично решен.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, но это уже я сам делал и не сработало.